# Finding the present value of the given cashflow.

Tags: finance

A loan is repayable by an annuity certain , which is payable annually in arrear for 16 years and calculated at effective rate of interest $5\%$ pa. The payments at  t=1 , t=2 , t=3 , t=4 , . . . . . . t=15 , t=16 are given as : (100 , 100 , 120 , 120 , . . . . . . . , 240 , 240) .

We need to find the amount of the loan , or the present value of these payments.

Present value at t=0 is given by ( $100v + 100 v^{2} + 120 v^{3} + 120v^{4} $ . . . . . $+ 240v^{15} + 240v^{16}$)  where , $ v = (1+i)^{-1}$.

It isn't solvable right away , so what I did was , combining the consecutive payments , thereby dealing with $8$ payments now , with rate of interest $ i^{'} = 10.25\%$. ( $1+ i^{'} = (1 + 1.05)^{2}$) where $i^{'}$ is the effective rate of interest for two years.

So the cashflow looks like this now : ( 200 , 240 , 280 , . . . . , 480).

I found out its present value as : $200 a_{[8]} + (40v)(Ia)_{[7]}$ , where , $ a_{[8]}$ is the present value of 8 payments of 1 unit for 8 years and $ (Ia)_{[7]}$ is the increasing annuity for 7 years.

Is the above relation OK ?

Comment: Why can't you directly use the formula for sum of a G.P. ?

Comment: What would be the common ratio ? @trueblueanil

Comment: You can't directly use the formula for the entire period, but you can sum up part by part for portions that have a common payment. Common ratio is $v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cash flow is equivalent to this
\begin{matrix}
t & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
\hline
A & 100 &  & 120 &  & 140 &  & 160 &  & 180 &  & 200 &  & 220 &  & 240 & \\
B & &    100 &  & 120 &  & 140 &  & 160 &  & 180 &  & 200 &  & 220 &  & 240
\end{matrix}
where the payment are made every two periods of compunding.

The interest is then $j=(1+i)^2-1=10.25\%$ and $v=\frac{1}{1+j}=0.907029$.
So we have for the cash flow $B$
$$
PV_B=100\,a_{\overline{8}|j}+20\,v\,(Ia)_{\overline{7}|j}= 845.13 
$$
and for the cash flow $A$
$$
PV_A=(1+i)PV_B= 887.38 
$$
and then the present value for the original cash flow is $PV=PV_A+PV_B=(2+i)PV_B$ that is
$$
PV=(2+i)\left[100\,a_{\overline{8}|j}+20\,v\,(Ia)_{\overline{7}|j}\right]= 1,732.51 
$$

Answer (score 1):

The cashflow for periods $(2n-1)$ and $2n$ are equal. Let this be $C_n$. These can be combined together into one cashflow in period $2n$ of $$C_n(1+i)+C_n=C_n(2+i)$$. From the cashflows given, $C_n=100+20(n-1)$.

Hence we have cashflows of 
$$(2+i)\{100,120,\cdots,240\}$$ 
for years $2,4,6,\cdots,16$.

**Taking two years as one period**, the interest rate becomes
$i'=(1+i)^2-1$.

Defining the discount factor for one period as $w=\dfrac 1{1+i'}=\dfrac 1{(1+i)^2}=v^2$, the present value can then be computed as

$$\begin{align}
(2+i)\left(100w+120w^2+\cdots+240w^8\right)
&=(2+i)\sum_{n=1}^8 (100+20(n-1))w^n\\
&=(2+i)\left(100a_{{\overline{8|}}i'}+20(Ia)_{{\overline{7|}}i'}\right)\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$